# Error message when renaming files on a network drive stored in Windows 7 favorites

Tags: windows-7, network-drive

I have a network drive mapped to a share on a Window Server 2003. I have a shortcut to this drive stored in my Windows 7 favorites. When I double click the shortcut and then rename a file on the drive, if the file is longer than 8 chars or contains spaces then I get this error

> The drive that this file or folder is stored on does not allow long file names, or names containing blanks or any of the following characters:...

If I get to the network drive by click on it in the tree under computer then it works fine. Is there a way to get round this?

(Update: sometimes the drive isn't available in the tree, even though it's mapped. I have to kill the explorer.exe process and restart it to make it appear in the tree.)

Comment: I also have this problem and get this error message. Specifically I CAN create/rename files in folders that I access via their Network path (eg \\Server\Share\Folder\File.doc) but I can NOT create/rename the same files in the same folders that I access via their Computer path (ie mapped network drive) (eg N:\Folder\Myfile.doc). I am running Windows 7, and the network storage device is a NAS (unix based). I happen to have Windows Synchronisation/Offline Folders enabled on this device.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that explorer hasn't finished loading properly.  Quickest fix seems to be; use task manager to end the explorer process then; use New Task to start it up again.